# how to check if the first element of string is a zero in TCL?

Tags: string, tcl

I have the following code in TCL:

```
set num1 "00"
set num2 "02"
set num3 "12"
```

I want to do is:
if the first digit is 0, then only take the second digit.
For example:

```
num1 is "00", then I will set num1 as "0"
num2 is "02", then I will set num1 as "2"
num3 is "12", then it is still "12"
```

how to check the first digit is zero?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `string first`, which returns the index of the first occurrence of a character. If it returns 0 (zero), the string begins with that character. Note, however, that if you have a really long string this could have performance implications, because if there are no zeros in the string it will examine every character until the end.

```
if {[string first 0 $num1] == 0} {
    set num1 [string range $num1 1 end]
}
```

Another choice is to use `string match`. This is arguably the most readable way to solve the problem, and will run very quickly.

```
if {[string match {0*} $num1]} {
    set num1 [string range $num1 1 end]
}
```

Yet another way is to get the first character and compare it to zero. Like using `string match`, this will run very quickly.

```
if {[string index $num1 0] == 0} {
    set num1 [string range $num1 1 end]
}
```

Comment: thanks Bryan  you can use string range ;-) if {[string range $num1 0 1] == "0" } { puts "it begins with a zero" } or string index if {[string index $num1 0] == "0
"

Comment: I really wouldn't use `string first` for this; it'll keep on searching even if the first character isn't `0`.

Answer (score 0):

To check if the first character is `0`, use `string match`:

```
if {[string match "0*" $str]} {
    set rest [string range $str 1 end]
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`scan`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/scan.htm) command is useful here

```
set num1 "00"
set num2 "02"
set num3 "12"
set num4 "08"   ;# an invalid octal number

foreach val [list $num1 $num2 $num3 $num4] {puts [scan $val %d]}
```

```
0
2
12
8
```

To save the value back to the variable:

```
foreach var {num1 num2 num3 num4} {
    set $var [scan [set $var] %d]
    puts "$var=[set $var]"
}
```

```
num1=0
num2=2
num3=12
num4=8
```